# Сколько можно создать EVENT событий в MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Сколько можно создать EVENT событий в MySQL?
В документации не нашел этой информации.

Я планирую создавать **очень много однотипных событий** вроде этого:

```
CREATE EVENT $event_name 
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL $bs_time MINUTE
DO
UPDATE " . PREFIX . "_users
SET `status` = 'wait', `time` = '$add_time'
WHERE `id` = '$id'
```

***Сроки у событий от 1 до 15 дней и их может быть сотни или даже тысячи.***

После срабатывания, EVENT удаляется.

Хочу понять, как это влияет на производительность, возможно есть ограничения?

Спасибо!

Comment: В 90% случаев, когда хочется менять БД по расписанию говорит о попытке решения задачи не с той стороны. Обычно достаточно записать в таблицу сразу время, после которого например считать статус wait. А определение статуса исходя из текущего времени в времени записанного в таблице возложить на того, кто будет получать данные

Answer (score 0):

Нет никаких ограничений на количество Stored Programms (процедуры, функции, триггеры, события). Пока под системными таблицами есть свободное место можно создавать event.
Явных ограничений нет. Попробовал создать 10 тысяч event, проблем при создании не возникло. 
По производительности есть подозрения что может стать бутылочным горлышком, нужно тестировать.